# Sort all node by using customize di:published on alfresco

Tags: javascript, lucene, alfresco

i developed my own dashlet to show documents by using alfresco. To short all feed document by published date. i used di:published property. it does not work, how to do it?

- my dashelet used search.lib.js file to  access repository data.
- to apply di:published property, modify xml file in alfresco

**share-config.custom.xml**

```
 <!-- cm:content type (existing nodes) -->
   <config  evaluator="node-type" condition="cm:content">
      <forms>
         <!-- Default form configuration used on the document details and edit metadata pages -->
         <form>
            <field-visibility>

               <show id="di:published" />
            </field-visibility>
         </form>

         <!-- Document Library pop-up Edit Metadata form -->
         <form id="doclib-simple-metadata">
            <field-visibility>

               <show id="di:published" />
            </field-visibility>
            <edit-form template="../documentlibrary/forms/doclib-simple-metadata.ftl" />
         </form>

         <!-- Document Library Inline Edit form -->
         <form id="doclib-inline-edit">
            <field-visibility>

               <show id="di:published" />
            </field-visibility>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>
```

Comment: I really have no idea what you are asking. What is it doing and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: You're showing the share-config.custom.xml and what has that to do with the filters you've mentioned? The filters are configured in the Freemarker, client-side JavaScript & Repository Webscripts

Answer (score 0):

I think your datatype is date and it is sorting data as string.Please verify this.If that is the problem than in feed.Return data as long for date.